# What's casting up class object in ArrayList?

Tags: java

The method below returns a List from a SQL DB, the List contains employees names. Can anyone explain to me what's the meaning of casting Class Objects for example:

`public List<Employee>` or `Employee tempEmployee = convertRowToEmployee(myRs);` ?

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() throws Exception {
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Statement myStmt = null;
    ResultSet myRs = null;

    try {
        myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from employees");

        while (myRs.next()) {
            Employee tempEmployee = convertRowToEmployee(myRs);
            list.add(tempEmployee);
        }
        return list;    
    }
    finally {
        close(myStmt, myRs);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't using a cast, this is using generic types. What part are you questioning?

Comment: Fixed the broken formatting in the Question.  (@nOOB ... it is >>your<< responsibility to make the Question legible.  Even if you are a noob.)

Comment: I agree.  The Question makes no sense.  There is no casting anywhere in the example code.

Answer (score 0):

`public` is the accessor type. This defines what other classes can access the method. `List` is the return type. So you need to return a value of the type `List`.

`Employee` is defining the type of variable you are declaring. You do this because the method `convertRowToEmployee`, I assume, returns a value of the type `Employee`

Nothing in the this code is cast.

Comment: i am sorry there was a mistake, i mean "public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() throws Exception {}" these method it's return list from sql DB, i am just need from u to explain to me this casting <Employee> this casting type it's class Object, and this class contain get and set methods, it's helper class to use it when get and seting values in JTable and thx for ur replay Sir

Comment: `List<Employee>` simply means that the method `getAllEmployees` will return a list of type `Employee`. Basically returning a list of employees.